# How to specify a physical path on disc to a file, but acces a memory location?

Tags: .net, file, memory, inputstream

I'm trying to integrate several components to build a custom reporting solution. One of these components is a template-based report generator. It reads a template consisting on a RTF file with placeholders and perform the substitution. This works great, and generates an RTF report.

Although it can generate the results as a stream instead of a physical RTF file, it has a property meant to specify the full name for the template (input) file. This is Ok on desktop applications but when talking about a WCF Service I would like to avoid the need to have a physical file in the HD.

All the templates are stored inside a database. The application reads it from there as a stream and then saves it to the HD as an RTF file. 
I'd like to know if it would be possible in c# to 'cheat' the report generator in such a way that I could specify a string consisting on a kind of 'virtual'  or 'fictitious' path and then the componet would open the template from a memory stream as it was a real physical path on disc.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Gonzalo

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how the reporting solution works, you may be able to use a named pipe. See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365150%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more information, but the basic gist is that you would call [`CreateNamedPipe`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CreateNamedPipe) and specify the name you want to use (in the format listed on that MSDN page), then pass that name as the file name to your reporting solution.

Comment: Ok Adam, Thanks a lot. I wil perform some research about NamedPipes.
Best wishes,

Gonzalo

Answer (score 1):

In C# 4 you can use memory mapped files: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/06/21/net-framework-4-0-using-memory-mapped-files.aspx

Comment: MMF allows to access file through memory interface. He needs the reverse: access memory through the file interface.

Comment: Ok Manu, that's a good clue, but I'm using c# 3.5 right now. If I change to C# 4 in the future I'll consider this alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If the RTF library supports loading RTF files from the internet using `WebRequest`, you could call [`WebRequest.RegisterPrefix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.registerprefix.aspx) to make it call your own `WebRequest` class for specific `Uri`s.  If it only uses `WebRequest` for paths that begin with `http`, you could register the prefix `http://MyNonExistantDomain.internal/`.

Comment: Hello SLaks,

Unfortunatelly, it doesn't support web requests.
Best regards,
Gonzalo